# Create GitHub repo from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-api

I have this function in my node project, that should create a new GitHub repository for a specific user:

```
exports.create_repo = function (repo) {
var options = {
    host: "api.github.com",
    path: "/user/repos?access_token=" + repo.accessToken,
    method: "POST",
    json: { name: repo.name },
    headers: { "User-Agent": "github-app" }
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
    var body = '';
    response.on("data", function(chunk){ body+=chunk.toString("utf8"); });

    response.on("end", function(){
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);
    });
});

request.end();
}
```

Every time I use it, the response is:

```
{ message: 'Not Found',
documentation_url: 'https://developer.github.com/v3' }
```

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a `curl -v` request? If so, can you post the full output of that request (but mask sensitive information, like OAuth tokens). Also, can you make sure that the token you are using has `public_repo` scope?